# JWT Authentication From Ingress in OpenShift

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

So I'm migrating some `Spring Boot` microservices from `Kubernetes` to `OpenShift`. Below is the simplified situation:

**Service 1:** Spring Boot application that handles, exposes 2 endpoints (`login` and `authenticate`). The `authenticate` service accepts the `Authorization` header containing a `JWT` token and validates that token. It returns 400 if the token doesn't exist and 403 is the user isn't authorized or the token is invalid and 200 if everything is valid.

**Service 2:** Spring Boot for some business service, exposes many endpoints and contains the annotation below in the Kubernetes Ingress so that all traffic is routed to the **Service 1** for authentication before actually reaching **Service 2**

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "http://service1/authenticate?url=$request_uri&method=$request_method"
```

The problem is that when I migrated to `OpenShift`, all applications are working fine but the annotation that should route traffic to **Service 1** doesn't seem to be working, since the `authenticate` service is never called.

I have searched the `OpenShift` documentation for days with no success, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this could help https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/serverless/networking/serverless-ossm-jwt.html, Openshift ServiceMesh include Istio. Here is how to configure Istio JWT https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authorization/authz-jwt/. So there you could configure the **Service 1** `authenticate`.

Comment: So this seems like it lets me configure Istio to replace the authenticate service, right? I didn't see and option to call an auth service, am I missing something?

Comment: I'm thinking about something like this https://www.keycloak.org/2018/02/keycloak-and-istio.html. I know it's a little bit out date but the pricinple is same.